# Create list from list of child object's list in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I have an object that looks like

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val states: List<State>
) {
    data class State(
        val name: String,
        val cities: List<City>
    )
    data class City(
        val name: String
    )
}
```

Given a Person such as:

```
Person(
    name = "dude",
    states = listOf(
        Person.State(
            name = "Utah",
            cities = listOf(
                name = "city 1",
                name = "city 2"
            )
        ),
        Person.State(
            name = "Colorado",
            cities = listOf(
                name = "city 3",
                name = "city 4"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How would I map this to a list of just the city names in Kotlin? Such as:

```
["city 1", "city 2", "city 3", "city 4"]
```

I know I could use a couple for loops, and just append to a separate array, taking an iterative approach, but I'm new to reactive kotlin and I'm trying to do this in a functional way using methods in the collections library. I can't use flatten() since it's not an array of arrays, but an object containing an array of objects that contains an array.

Comment: `people.flatMap(Person::states).flatMap(Person.State::cities).map(Person.City::name)`

Comment: Or, equivalently: `people.flatMap{ it.states }.flatMap{ it.cities }.map{ it.name }`. (I generally find this lambda style a little easier to read, though I know some people prefer the method reference style. Any differences in efficiency are likely to be insignificant.)

Comment: @gidds, It's compiled identically either way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think I've seen claims that the lambda approach gives an extra method with an extra method call — though maybe that was with a different, non-inline method. In this case, you're right: the two approaches do generate identical bytecode. (Confirmed with command-line kotlinc v1.6.10.) Even if not, though, the difference generally wouldn't be worth worrying about; it's much more important to write clear code that's easy for humans to read and maintain (which also tends to make it easy for the JVM to optimise).

Comment: That’s probably true for Sequences since the operators aren’t inlined.

Comment: @user406955 _listOf(
                name = "city 1",
                name = "city 2"
            )_ in your post is not correct. It should read: _listOf(
        Person.City(name = "city 1"),
        Person.City(name = "city 2")
      )_. Same for the second list.

Comment: @Tenfour and gidds: It is not necessary to _flatMap_ the first level. _val result = person.states.flatMap { ..._ will do.